# Encoding json in the form of {index: {key1: value1, key2: valu2, .... }} where index = key1 in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am taking the result of a query and converting it to json. See my code here -

```
$sql = "select * from students";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if($query->num_rows() != 0 ){
    $result = $query->result();
    $data = json_encode($result);
}
```

So, for the two rows in my table *students* the **data** is like -

```
[{"id": "1", "name": "foo", "email": "foo@example.com"}, {"id": "2", "name": "bar", "email": "bar@example.com"}]
```

So basically I get an array. 
But I want to encode it like -

```
{"1": {"id": "1", "name": "foo", "email": "foo@example.com"}, "2": {"id": "2", "name": "bar", "email": "bar@example.com"}}
```

So that my data is like index: {key1: val1, key2: val2} where index is key1. How do I do this?

The reason for the data in this for is my js which uses above data to give ids to my checkboxes -

```
destTable = $('#dataTable');
$.post("/examplec/getData",
        params, function(data) {
        var newRow;
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        $(json).each(function(i,val){
            newRow = "<tr><td style='right:10px'><input type='checkbox' name = 'case' class = 'case' id=" + i + " onclick='checkAll();'></td>";
            $.each(val,function(k,v){
                newRow = newRow + "<td>" + v + "</td>";
            });
            newRow = newRow + "</tr>";
            destTable.append(newRow);
        });

});
```

A model from MVC patter returns a data to the controller *examplec.php* . But I want the id of each checkbox to be the **id** from my **data**.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Accessing either object would work in exactly the same way.

Comment: http://php.net/json_encode - check the second parameter

Comment: @Asad see the modified question for the reason I want the data in that form.

Comment: Also even when I get the data in the form I have said I want it to be, how do I parse it with jquery's parseJSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On PHP 5.3+ you can do:

```
$data = json_encode($result, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php):

> **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT**
>   Outputs an object rather than an array when a non-associative array is used. Especially useful when the recipient of the output is expecting an object and the array is empty. Available since PHP 5.3.0.

Edit: you don't need the ID as the key, doing that you're just duplicating data. You can access the `id` property and assign it as the checkbox id:

```
newRow = "<tr><td style='right:10px'><input type='checkbox' name = 'case' class = 'case' id='" + val.id + "' onclick='checkAll();'></td>";
```

Comment: This pretty much gives the OP what he wants but the index starts at 0, I think he wanted 1,2,3, etc

Comment: I want to put the index as the id of each check box. So with this id I can do the transactions with the db because this id of checkbox will be the id of _students_ table. So how do I parse this form in jquery?

Comment: @HussainTamboli see my edit, you can still access the ID and set it to the checkbox id.

Answer (score 2):

You could go like this:

```
$results = $query->result();

$data = array();

foreach($results as $result)
{
    // Assuming it returns objects, not arrays, else use $result["id"]
    $data[$result->id] = $result;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: hi, With your code I get the json in the required form but jquery's parseJSON can't parse this. any idea why?

Comment: What response are you getting from the PHP? I got...

{"1":{"id":"1","name":"foo","email":"foo@example.com"},"2":{"id":"2","name":"bar","email":"bar@example.com"}}

to me it looks like it's already an object

You could surround it in single quotes and then parse but I don't think it's necessary

http://jsfiddle.net/AnpnZ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * from students";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$res=array();
if($query->num_rows() != 0 ){
    $result = $query->result();
    $res[]=$result;

}
$data = json_encode($res);
```